# Wordpress process [bracket tag] in theme/plug PHP coding

Tags: php, wordpress, revolution-slider

I have recently installed Revolution Slider on Wordpress, created a slider with 3 sample images, and installed it on a page by adding this string in the content section:

```
[rev_slider nonimage1]
<!-- note: other HTML before and after works OK too -->
```

which then gets parsed on page load and the slider loads and works fine.

However, in /wp-admin if I go to `Appearance > Themes` and edit one of the PHP pages as follows:

```
//break out of php here...
?>
[rev_slider nonimage1]
<?php
//and back in we go...
```

The bracketed string (edit: I understand is called a "shortcode") is not processed.

As I'm new to Wordpress I'm still looking into the processing order, but is there a WP equivalent processor method similar to what is used in an HTML content section, that I can apply here?  Something like:

```
WP_God_Class::processThis('[rev_slider nonimage1]');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Bracketed string" - tag, is not processed, because it have to be called from shortcode action. TinyMCE and the_content() doing it automatically.

If you would echo shortcode result in your files, use

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[rev_slider nonimage1]' ) ?>
```

If you would parse tag from HTML it's seems like unpossible, because it have to be converted in PHP.

Alternatively, if you would parse it from wrapped HTML it should works with

```
<?php 
$content = 'abc <br> [rev_slider nonimage1] def';
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
?>
```

Comment: FEB (for everyone's benefit, needs to be an acronym like that :) the 1st `do_shortcode( )` did not work but the second suggestion `apply_filters( )` did.  Any suggestions on why would make this post more helpful, thanks!